# Array Arithmetical Operations

Tags: c

I understand what p,p[3],p[1] in the following code would mean individually, but need help figuring out what they do in the following code:

```
char c[] = "GATE2017";
    char *p = c;
    printf("\n%s", p + p[3] - p[1]);
```

Comment: No matter what you ask, people will always downvote you.

Comment: What output did you get?

Comment: What does `p[3]` contain?  What does `p[1]` contain?  What happens when you add or subtract (or add and subtract) integers and pointers?  So what does `p + p[3] - p[1]` evaluate too?  So what gets printed?  Why isn't there a newline at the end of the output to ensure it gets printed in a timely manner?

Comment: The output comes to 2017.p is the entire Array. p[1] comes to A. p[3] comes to E. But I cant understand how they go together.

Comment: `p[3]` is `E` (ascii code 69), `p[1]` is `A` (65). So `69-65 = 4` and when you add 4 to `p` it means it points to the `2` and so prints from there.

Comment: More accurately, `p` points to the start of the array (rather than being the entire array).  Adding or subtracting an integer changes what the pointer points at.  The difference between `'E'` and `'A'` is 4, so the expression is equivalent to `p + 4`.  Would it have been any clearer written as `&p[p[3] - p[1]]`?  Do you see why those expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Change to `printf("%c\n", *(p + p[3] - p[1]));` You should see what is going on.